# unable to set diagonal values to None in df (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I have a dataframe with date as the index and a correlation matrix for a set of securities at each date - essentially a rolling correlation matrix.

I can't seem to get this to work:

```
tmp = temp_table.apply(lambda x: np.fill_diagonal(x.values, None))
```

as I'm getting the following error "array must be at least 2-d...". This is strange as temp_table.ndim = 2.

would anyone be able to help please?

Comment: apply iterates on rows. passing one at a time to the lambda

Answer (score 0):

Use `fill_diagonal` on whole dataset instead of row:

```
tmp = np.fill_diagonal(temp_table.values, None)
```